# I have a problem or upload the file in cloudinary in node.js where image come from react native and clodinary setup in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express, cloudinary

I face a problem for uploading the image to cloudinary. When i upload the image from my react native app its first change the image into base base 64 and send it into the backend but when the code reaches to the upload system its give the error

```
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
```

I dont know why i upload the image from phone and this case occur that no path found. i share all my code because i don't understand why its happening.

My credentials of cloudinary are ok so there is no issue with cloudinary api. i have checked it several times.

Here is my reactnative component which have the form

```
     import { View,Text,Button,StyleSheet,Image,KeyboardAvoidingView,Keyboard 
        } from "react-native";
        import {Picker} from "@react-native-picker/picker"
        import React from "react";
        import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
        import { TextInput } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
        import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
        import {useDispatch,useSelector} from "react-redux"
        import { RegisterClass,GetClassessInfo, addAdmin } from '../../actions/adminAction';
        import { useState ,useEffect} from "react";
        import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
        import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
        
        export default function ManageAdmin(){
            const {isAuthenticated,admin}=useSelector((state)=>state.admin)
            const [name,setname]=useState("");
            const [email,setemail]=useState("");
            const [phone,setphone]=useState("");
            const [address,setaddress]=useState("");
            const [password,setpassword]=useState(""); 
            const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
            const [avatar,setAvatar] =useState(null);
            const navigation=useNavigation();
            const dispatch=useDispatch();
            console.log(admin);
           // console.log("error");
            //console.log(loading);
            //console.log(isAuthenticated);
            
            const AdminSubmit=async()=>{
                dispatch(addAdmin(name,email,address,phone,password,image ))
            }
        
            
            
        useEffect(()=>{
        if(isAuthenticated){
            //console.log(user);
        }
          
        },[])
        
        /*const handleImageSelect = async () => {
          const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== 'granted') {
            return;
          }
        
          const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [1, 1],
            quality: 1,
          });
        
          if (!result.canceled) {
            const selectedAsset = result.assets[0];
            const base64Image = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(selectedAsset.uri, {
              encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
            });
            setAvatar(result.uri);
            setImage(base64Image);
        
            // Use the base64Image as needed
            console.log(base64Image);
            const selectedAsset = result.assets[0];
            setAvatar(result.uri);
            setImage(selectedAsset.uri);
        
            // Use the image URI as needed
            console.log(selectedAsset.uri);
          }
        };*/
        /*const handleImageSelect = async () => {
          const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== 'granted') {
            return;
          }
        
          const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [1, 1],
            quality: 1,
          });
        
          if (!result.cancelled) {
            const { uri } = result;
            setAvatar(uri);
            setImage(uri);
            console.log(uri);
          }
        };
        */
        const handleImageSelect = async () => {
          const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== 'granted') {
            return;
          }
        
          const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [1, 1],
            quality: 1,
          });
        
          if (!result.canceled) {
            const selectedAsset = result.assets[0];
            const base64Image = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(selectedAsset.uri, {
              encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
            });
            setAvatar(result.uri);
            setImage(base64Image);
        
            // Use the base64Image as needed
            console.log(base64Image);
          }
        };
        const convertImageToBase64 = async (imageUri) => {
          try {
            console.log(imageUri);
            const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(imageUri, {
              encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
            });
            return base64;
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error converting image to base64:', error);
            return null;
          }
        };
                 
            return(
        
               <View style={styles.Mainview}>
                 
                 
                  <View style={styles.Mvinnertwo}>
                  
                  <View style={styles.Loginform}>
                  <View style={styles.Loginformfields}>
                  <TextInput style={styles.MvinneroneInputSearch}   placeholder="name "  value={name} onChangeText={text => setname(text)} ></TextInput>
                  <TextInput style={styles.MvinneroneInputSearch}   placeholder="email" value={email} onChangeText={text => setemail(text)}></TextInput>
                  <TextInput style={styles.MvinneroneInputSearch}   placeholder="phone"  value={phone} onChangeText={text => setphone(text)}></TextInput>
                  <TextInput style={styles.MvinneroneInputSearch}   placeholder="address" value={address} onChangeText={text => setaddress(text)} ></TextInput>
                  <TextInput style={styles.MvinneroneInputSearch}   placeholder="password" value={password} onChangeText={text => setpassword(text)}></TextInput>
                  <Button title="Select Image" onPress={handleImageSelect} />
                    {avatar && <Image source={{ uri: avatar }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
                  </View>       
                  <View style={styles.signIN}>
                  <View style={styles.signINbutton}>
                    <Button title="Add Admin" color="#7956b5" 
                      onPress={AdminSubmit}
                    ></Button>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.signUpbutton}>
                    <Button title="View All Classes" color="#7956b5" ></Button>
                    </View>
                  </View> 
        
                  </View>
                   
                   </View>
                   
                 </View>
                 
           );
        }
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          Mainview:{
            height:"100%",
            backgroundColor:"#7956b5",
            alignItems:"center"
          },
          Mvinnerone:{
          //  flex:1,
            
           
            height:"35%",
            flexDirection:'column'
          },
         
          Mvinnerone1Image:{
            marginLeft:-20,
            alignItems:'flex-start',
            width:150,
            height:150
          },
          Mvinnerone1:{
           flexDirection:'row'
          },
          Mvinnerone1view1:{
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'flex-start',
            width:"30%",
            
          },
          Mvinnerone1view2:{ 
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
            width:"70%",
            fontSize:20
          },
          Mvinnerone1view2Text:{
            fontSize:20,
            color:'white'
          },
          MvinneroneInput:{
           justifyContent:'center',
           alignItems:'center'
          },
          MvinneroneInputSearch:{
            //justifyContent:'center',
             //alignItems:'center',
            marginTop:20,
            backgroundColor:'white',
            width:'100%',
            padding:'2%',
            borderColor:"#7956b5",
            borderWidth:2,
            borderRadius:10
          },
        
          Mvinnertwo: {
            padding:"5%",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            width:"95%",
            height:'100%',
            borderColor:'white',
            borderWidth:1,
            borderRadius:20,
            shadowColor:"black",
            shadowOffset:2,
          },
          Row1:{
            flexDirection:'row',
           
            height:100,
            justifyContent:'center',
            
          },
          cel1:{
            justifyContent:"center",
            alignItems:"center",
            width:"25%",
            
            margin:10,
            borderColor:"#7956b5",
            borderWidth:2,
            borderRadius:10,
            shadowColor:'#000',
            shadowOffset:{width:0,height:7},
            shadowOpacity:0.43,
            shadowRadius:9.51 
          },
          cel2:{
            justifyContent:"center",
            alignItems:"center",
           width:"25%",
           
           margin:10,
           borderColor:"#7956b5",
            borderWidth:2,
            borderRadius:10
          },
          cel3:{
            justifyContent:"center",
            alignItems:"center",
          width:"25%",
          
          margin:10,
          borderColor:"#7956b5",
            borderWidth:2,
            borderRadius:10
          },
          forgotpass:{
            flexDirection:'row',
            justifyContent:'flex-end',
            marginTop:4,
            marginBottom:4
          },
          signIN:{
            marginTop:'2%',
            justifyContent:"center"
          },
          signINbutton:{
            marginBottom:6
          },
          Loginform:{
            //alignItems:"center"
          }
          });
```

Here is the action which target the backend api

```
    export const addAdmin = (name,email,phone,address,password,image) => async (dispatch) => {
        try {
          dispatch({ type: Add_Admin_Request }); 
      
       //   const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };
          console.log("yes");
          console.log(image);
          const { data } = await axios.post(
            `http://192.168.100.42:4000/api/v1/RegisterAdmin`,
            { name,email,phone,address,password,image },
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              },
            }           
          );
          console.log("After Posting");
          console.log(data);
          dispatch({ type:  Add_Admin_Success, payload: data.user });
          
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) {
            dispatch({ type: Add_Admin_Fail, payload: error.response.data.message });
          } else {
            dispatch({ type: Add_Admin_Fail, payload: "An error occurred" });
          }
        }
      };
```

Here is the reducer

```
    export const adminProfileReducer=(state={admin:{}},action)=>{
    
        
        switch(action.type){
            case Get_AdminOWNPROFILE_REQUEST:
                case Add_Admin_Request:
               return{
                    loading:true,
                    isAuthenticated:false
                };
                case Get_AdminOWNPROFILE_SUCCESS:
                    case Add_Admin_Success:
                    
                    return{
                        
                        ...state,
                        loading:false,
                        isAuthenticated:true,
                        //adminProfileInfo:action.payload
                        user:action.payload
                    };
    
                    
    
                    case Get_AdminOWNPROFILE_FAIL:
                        case Add_Admin_Fail:
                    return{
                        ...state,
                        loading:false,
                        isAuthenticated:false,
                        user:null,
                        error:action.payload
                    };
    
                /*case CLEAR_ERRORS:
            
                 return{
                ...state,
                error:null
        
        
               };*/
               default:{
                return  state;
              }
        }
    }
```

Here is the backend which have the cloudinary system

```
exports.registerAdmin = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("1");
  cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: '<CLOUD_NAME>',
    api_key: '<API_KEY>',
    api_secret: '<API_SECRET>'
  });
  console.log(req.body.image);

  try {
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.image, {
      folder: 'avatar'
    });
    console.log('Image uploaded to Cloudinary:', result);
    const { public_id, secure_url } = result;
    
    const { name, email, password, phone, address } = req.body;

    const user = await admin.create({
      name,
      email,
      password,
      phone,
      address,
      image: {
        public_id,
        url: secure_url
      }
    });

    console.log("Admin created:", user);
    sendToken(user, 201, res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading image to Cloudinary:', error);
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: In the above code snippets you shared, you are exposing your Cloudinary API Secret which should be kept secure and not shared anywhere. I urge you to log in to your Cloudinary account, go to the Settings > Access Keys tab and disable the existing API Key/Secret pair that is exposed here. Then you can generate a new pair of API Key/Secret credentials from the same page and use those in your application code. Exposing the credentials allows anyone to make API calls to your Cloudinary account on your behalf and therefore, those credentials need to be disabled right away.